# Eigen::Quaterniond to Eigen::AngleAxis

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to convert an Eigen::Quaterniond to a Eigen::Vector3d representing a rotation vector (angle * axis). My thought was to convert it into an Eigen::AngleAxis format and then convert that to Eigen::Vector3d .

Is there a direct function to go from Eigen::Quaterniond to Eigen::AngleAxis?

Comment: As of now, just convert to AngleAxis and multiply the vector by the angle.

Comment: Yeah thats what I want to do. Is there a function to convert from quaternion to axis angle?

Comment: Just assign your quaternion to an `Eigen::AngleAxis` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a unit quaternion to an AngleAxis with the equal operator [see eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html#aa79ba9655d1b8fe12d75082902cea88b)

Comment: Interesting that assignment works, but not initialization: No viable conversion from 'Eigen::Quaterniond' (aka 'Quaternion<double>') to 'Eigen::AngleAxisd' (aka 'AngleAxis<double>') -- error I am getting.